# Merge image on double Tap

Tags: iphone, ios, image, gestures

I have two ImageViews and I am merging two images. First image is a **bodyImage** and second Image is a **tattooImage**. I already done merging, but I wants ask

1)I can drag tattooImage over bodyImage. I wants on doubleTap tattooImage mergeWith bodyImage on the tap coordinates. Hope you understand question

**Thanks**

[image] + [image]  =   [image]

**and here is my code :  here imageView1 is my bodyImage and imageView2 is my tattooImage**

```
- (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    int width=500;
    int height=500;
    NSLog(@"takephoto from twitter");



    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [imageView1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable


    [imageView2.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(180,200,200,200) blendMode:kCGBlendModeDarken alpha:0.4];



    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    imageView1.image=newImage;

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

mask image http://www.developers-life.com/resize-and-mask-an-image.html

Answer (score 0):

You need image masking for that. I wrote a [tutorial on how to use it](http://jeroendeleeuw.com/post/33638733049), and how I've used it in my own application. From the Apple documentation:

> Masking techniques can produce many interesting effects by controlling which parts of an image are painted. You can:
>
> - Apply an image mask to an image. You can also use an image as a mask
>   to achieve an effect that’s opposite from applying an image mask.
> - Use color to mask parts of an image, which includes the technique
>   referred to as chroma key masking.
> - Clip a graphics context to an
>   image or image mask, which effectively masks an image (or any kind of
>   drawing) when Quartz draws the content to the clipped context.